# Guard-rspec doesn't follow any changes

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

I'm coding a simple kata with rspec/guard. I've updated gem guard-rspec to version 4.2.8. This is my Guardfile:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
end
```

And when I use command **guard** I have to push enter every time when I want to launch tests. Why doesn't guard follow my files/changes and send me notifications?

One question yet - is it normal that with above guardfile configuration only specs files should be following, without an application's code?

Comment: You should `watch` all the files for witch you want to trigger rspec.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zishe/10217821 this is typical guard file, that including all necessary files.

Comment: I had the same problem with ROR 5.1.5. The solution that I found is explained at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227350/586195